# Replace string by calling method

Tags: javascript, html

I have already got this working, but I know there must be a more succinct way of doing it.

Using onBlur on a text field in the html page, it calls a method which replaces the value of the string if the value is empty or NaN.

JS:

```
function checkStr(str) {
        return str.value = "0";
}
```

HTML:

```
onblur="if(this.value=='' || isNaN(this.value)){this.value=checkStr(this.value)};"
```

So this does work, but seems exhaustive. Using:

```
function checkStr(str) {
    if (str.value == "" || isNaN(str.value)) {
        return str.value = "0";
    }
}
```

In the JS file, and:

```
onblur="checkStr(this.value);"
```

In the HTML doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You said you tried `onblur="checkStr();" ` in the HTML... did you pass the value?  Like this: `onblur="checkStr(this.value);" `

Comment: Yes I did, sorry that was an error. Corrected now.

Comment: What do you want to do with the return value?  Are you trying to set the input field to 0 if they don't enter a number?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. On exiting the field if the value is null or NaN it should set the value to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second method isn't assigning anything to textbox value, so you really need the following , i.e. passing in the textbox into the function

```
onblur="checkStr(this);"
```

and then for the function to check and assign the textbox

```
function checkStr(textbox) {
    if (textbox.value == "" || isNaN(textbox.value)) {
        textbox.value = "0";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`str` is your string, so you don't need to do `str.value`:

```
function checkStr(str) {
    if (str == "" || isNaN(str)) {
        return "0";
    }
}
```

And set `onblur` to actually set the input's value (as @chris mentions.)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct in my assumptions, and you're trying to set the value to `0` if the current value is not a number, or there *is* no value, I'd suggest (if you must use in-line JavaScript):

```
onblur="checkStr(this);"
```

Coupled with:

```
function checkStr(el) {
    el.value = !!!(1 * el.value) ? 0 : el.value;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eRbTQ/).

Answer (score 0):

What you tried looks close, but if you pass `this.value` to the function, then you shouldn't check `str.value` within the function.

Also, you need to return the correct value if the validation passes.  And assign the value back to the field when the value returns.

I think you need something like this:

```
<input type="text" onblur="this.value = checkStr(this.value);" />​
```

Then in the js...

```
function checkStr(str) {
    if (str == "" || isNaN(str)) {
        return "0";
    } else {
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: provide both by all means as it proves an working answer - it just annoys me to just see the fiddle